# Placeholder inside define constant mysql statement

Tags: php, mysql

Hey everyone I created a define constant mysql statement, using a where condition with one variable, is no problem but i encountered an error, when the placeholder the variable is array like this one.

```
        define ("GET_EMAIL_NOT_REG",    "SELECT DISTINCT  email   
                            FROM   accounts 
                            WHERE  sent = 0 
                            AND    active > 0
                            AND    email NOT IN ( ? )");
```

Pls correct me with the proper syntax as I encountered error using that code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use GROUP BY like:

```
        define ("GET_EMAIL_NOT_REG",    "SELECT DISTINCT  email   
                        FROM   accounts 
                        WHERE  sent = 0 
                        AND    active > 0
                        AND    email NOT IN ( ? )
                        GROUP BY email");
```